# Configuring sendmail to forward mail for a specific domain to a specific mail server without using MX records?

Tags: linux, sendmail

I am new to sendmail and would like to configure sendmail to forward all mail for a specific email address to another internal mail server. I need it to ignore the MX records and only send it to the server I specify but am not sure which files to edit or how to configure the sendmail config. Is it sufficient to add the server to the /etc/hosts and the /etc/mail/local-host-names files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** seems like you are talking about mail aliases.
Look into `/etc/aliases` or `/etc/mail/aliases`. After editing that file, run `newaliases`

---

I do not believe that `Sendmail` has transport map capabilities, at least not that i know of.
The feature you are looking for is available in `Postfix` out of the box. Not sure how much this answer would help you though...

There used to be a package called `redhat-switchmail` that kind of accomplished that, but I am not sure if it is still available, or if its even compatible with your system.

`/etc/mail/local-host-names` is just for that... local host names... the domains your sendmail server accepts mail for.

What exactly you want to accomplish with `/etc/hosts` I am not sure...

Depending on your configuration and version of your `Sendmail`, you need to edit `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` and then "make it" into `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf`. On older versions, you edit `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf`, but i do not suggest you touch either one of those files if you do not know what you are doing. They are pretty cryptic, to say the least.